# Fear of talking with native English speakers - how to overcome it

Tags: spoken-english, conversation

I'm Japanese and I can speak English decently well. When I talk with non native speakers, my grammar is 95% accurate I would say, but when it comes to talking with the native speakers, I don't know why but I feel more afraid and worried about making mistakes even though I know they won't care about it. And I tend to not be able to speak as fluently/smoothly when talking with them.

Is there anyone that has the same problems as me?

Answer (score 1):

この文章を書いて間違いを犯したかどうかはわかりませんが、あなたを愛しています。

What did you feel when you read this sentence? I think the most important thing for you is to understand. In spite of the fact that there might be some mistakes but you tried to think and do your best to understand me.

If you find a mistake, I think you may laugh and feel happy and you may teach me how to do it the right way. This is how native English speakers feel.

Please, don't be shy while speaking with a different language. A mistake in a language is not like stealing or killing or telling a lie. It's a funny thing and it's a good opportunity to learn from others.

I'm not a native English speaker but I also teach my mother tongue language and I enjoy listening to the bad grammar and terrible vocabulary of learners lol :)

A non-native English speaker speaks slowly (unlike the native speakers) so it's normal to find it a little hard to understand native speakers and that's okay. That shouldn't make you feel shy.

Answer (score 1):

You just speak. While you have emotions, speak!

You are not perfect, true. But neither are the native speakers of other languages.

Consider this: you are a native Japanese speaker. Did you never make any mistake while speaking Japanese? Does everybody in Japan speak Japanese perfectly without any error ever?

It is the same with any other language, English included. Native English-speaking people are equally people as you are.

If somebody will make ill-intended fun of your mistakes, it is their problem. Don't feel bad. If they make friendly fun - join the group and make fun yourself.

With enough practice, you will no longer feel the "fear". Just do it!